# Emacs: scroll buffer not point

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to scroll the entire visible portion of the buffer in Emacs, but leave point where it is. Example: point is towards the bottom of the window and I want to see some text which has scrolled off the top of the window without moving point.

Edit: I suppose `C-l` `C-l` sort of does what I wanted.

Comment: `C`- `l` clears the screen

Comment: In a terminal, yes, but not in Emacs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try these. Change `M-n` and `M-p` key bindings according to your taste

```
;;; scrollers
(global-set-key "\M-n" "\C-u1\C-v")
(global-set-key "\M-p" "\C-u1\M-v")
```

Comment: +1 I use something similar: `(global-set-key "\M-n"  (lambda () (interactive) (scroll-up   4)) )` and `(global-set-key "\M-p"  (lambda () (interactive) (scroll-down 4)) )`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the point will still move with after it hits the top or bottom of the window. I wonder if this is possible to avoid (without a retooling of Emacs itself)...

Comment: @celwell: True, but I'm happy with it as a workable solution.

Comment: @celwell There are variables that control the cursor's sensitivity to the window bounds. Perhaps you could put the scroll-down part inside a "let" block? Another thing one could try would be "save-excursion", although I'm not sure that that works with scrolling commands.

Answer (score 11):

```
;;;_*======================================================================
;;;_* define a function to scroll with the cursor in place, moving the
;;;_* page instead
;; Navigation Functions
(defun scroll-down-in-place (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (previous-line n)
  (unless (eq (window-start) (point-min))
    (scroll-down n)))

(defun scroll-up-in-place (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (next-line n)
  (unless (eq (window-end) (point-max))
    (scroll-up n)))

(global-set-key "\M-n" 'scroll-up-in-place)
(global-set-key "\M-p" 'scroll-down-in-place)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, scrolls in place, relative to the cursor/pointer. Thanks!!

Comment: To avoid compiler warnings, I replaced `(previous-line n)` with `(forward-line (* -1 n))`  and `(next-line n)` with `(forward-line n)`

Comment: This actually works, but only if I switch the `previous-line` and `next-line` around, because it otherwise jumps by two lines

Comment: Since `M-p` and `M-n` are often reserved for other things, I bind these to `C-S-y` and `C-S-e` since they're about the same as Vim's `CTRL_e` and `CTRL_y`.

Answer (score 8):

This might be of use. According to the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Scrolling) page on Scrolling;

> The variable `scroll-preserve-screen-position` may be useful to some.
>   When you scroll down, and up again, point should end up at the same
>   position you started out with. The value can be toggled by the built
>   in mode `M-x scroll-lock-mode`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is better:

```
(defun gcm-scroll-down ()
      (interactive)
      (scroll-up 1))
    (defun gcm-scroll-up ()
      (interactive)
      (scroll-down 1))
    (global-set-key [(control down)] 'gcm-scroll-down)
    (global-set-key [(control up)]   'gcm-scroll-up)
```

reference : [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Scrolling#toc2)

Comment: Why do you think it's better? (And what does your code do?)

Comment: It *is* better: it moves the view, not the point ; thanks **a lot** @Bilal

Answer (score 1):

Based on Bilal's answer:

```
(global-set-key [(meta down)] (lambda () (interactive) (scroll-down 1)))
(global-set-key [(meta up)] (lambda () (interactive) (scroll-up 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;; Preserve the cursor position relative to the screen when scrolling
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position 'always)

;; Scroll buffer under the point
;; 'scroll-preserve-screen-position' must be set to a non-nil, non-t value for
;; these to work as intended.
(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") #'scroll-down-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") #'scroll-up-line)
```