# Emacs: how do you disable auto-recentering?

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs on Mac OS and cannot seem to disable auto-recentering feature; it keeps jumping buffer window so that cursor is in the middle of screen. I tried setting "scroll-step=20, scroll-conservatively=200", and it works for a couple of hours and then it starts all over again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How to scroll line by line in GNU Emacs?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128927/how-to-scroll-line-by-line-in-gnu-emacs)

Comment: I have found a conflict with `line-spacing` and `scroll-step` with Emacs Trunk `--with-ns`, so I haven't used `line-spacing` since.  I also didn't have any luck with `scroll-conservatively`, so I just use `scroll-step`.  I tried `auto-window-vscroll` tonight and didn't see any adverse affects, so I may keep that setting as Michael is suggesting.  I think long lines with `visual-line-mode` also have something to do with the behavior you describe.

Comment: I thought I had this working by setting scroll-conservatively to 1 instead of a large value, but then a couple hours later the behavior started again as you described.  This is driving me crazy using terminal emacs on os x on a small screen.  It's practically unusable at times.

Answer (score 8):

In my .emacs I have

```
(setq scroll-step 1)
(setq scroll-conservatively 10000)
(setq auto-window-vscroll nil)
```

That seems to work well for me.

Comment: Thank you - sanity restored. Why anyone thinks that auto-vscrolling should be on by default is beyond me.